# How can we get response after sending Email via Mail funtion in Php

Tags: php, email

I am writing a code to verify Email address by sending a test email and checking their response. If the response is positive then I considered an email as a verified email. But I am using the mail function in PHP to send email, but I am not able to get any response after sending email, I s there any way that I will get the response that message is delivered or bounced after sending the email.

```
    <?php
          $to = "root@localhost.com";
          $subject = "Hi!";
          $body="test";

          $headers = "From: root@localhost.com"; 

          if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
             echo "Message successfully sent!";
          } else {
             echo "Message delivery failed...";
          }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the return value :
Return Value:   Returns the hash value of the address parameter, or FALSE on failure. Note: Keep in mind that even if the email was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the email is actually sent and received!